# jQuery change function not working

Tags: jquery, onchange

I can't seem to get this working seems like it should

```
$('.titleother').change(function() {

if ($('.titleother').val() == 'Other') {
    ​$('.hiddentext').css('display','block')
}​​​

})
```

For this HTML

```
<select class="titleother">​
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<p class="hiddentext" style="display:none">TEXT</p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure it doesn't [work](http://jsfiddle.net/amuec/)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: in place of if ($('.titleother').val() == 'Other')  ​$('.hiddentext').css('display','block')
the better way is: ​$('.hiddentext').toggle($(this).val() == 'Other');

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works for me using Chrome:

```
$(function(ready){
    $('.titleother').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            $('.hiddentext').show();   
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amuec/11/

(Darin's code didn't work for me either)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you put this in a `$(document).ready` so that the DOM is ready when you attach the `.change()` handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.titleother').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            ​$('.hiddentext').show();
        }​​​
    });
});
```

Comment: That fiddle works for me? You sure you have javascript enabled?

Comment: Yea definitely got javascript enabled - I'm using Safari on Mac - but have tried it in Chrome too and it doesn't work

Comment: @Jamie can you try this in a separate file, not jsfiddle? It seems like a bug there.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, for some reason your code has a \u200b zero-width space which causes the code to not to run.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing `;`
**[Check here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MMasr/)**

Comment: Did you get any errors?I tested in firefox.Its working fine for me.

Comment: Are you looking for when 1 and 2 is selected it needs to be hide?